# Set backgrond of QML TreeView

Tags: qt, qml

I want to set a background colour for my tree view but cannot find a way.
Say I have the following

```
Rectangle {
    width: 800
    height: 800
    anchors.fill: parent

    TreeView {
        id: view
        model: theModel
    }
}
```

What do I need to set a background color?

Setting a color on the parent does not work and I cannot see how to use TreeViewStyle to do this.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html
You can customize the look by overriding the itemDelegate, rowDelegate, or headerDelegate properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the property `backgroundVisible: false` (and `alternatingRowColors: false` if needed).

The delegate is not affected by this property. You may need to define a new one without a background.